# How to get the same cookies like browser using python request

Tags: facebook, python-requests

I'm trying to write an app that can login into Facebook Authentication with Python and Requests. I've tried using the code below but it doesn't log into facebook.

```
import requests
payload = {'email:'xxx','pass':'xxx'}
session = requests.session()
r = session.get("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F7s.safaricom.co.ke%2Fsu7s%2Fproc%2Ffb-login.php&state=<state>&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3&display=popup&scope=read_stream%2Cfriends_likes%2Cpublish_actions%2Cuser_friends",params=payload)
```

It doesn't log in even with the correct username and password, the same input works if you visit the link with a browser.

Comment: You are not supposed to log in server-side – the OAuth flow requires an active user logging in on the client-side. And of course Facebook has measures in place to try and prevent what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set a session first if you want requests to keep track of cookies for you.

Should be

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
r = session.get('https://blahblahblah.com/etc')
```

Then requests will automatically handle the cookies for you.

Comment: It's returning 200 success but it doesn't log in successfully. https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=465552070224966&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F7s.safaricom.co.ke%2Fsu7s%2Fproc%2Ffb-login.php&state=be2d5bbeb1bae6101ba393bd30c0e541&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3&display=popup&scope=read_stream%2Cfriends_likes%2Cpublish_actions%2Cuser_friends that's the facebook app for safaricom

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri The question asked how to use cookies with python-requests. My answer addressed that. I'm not sure about the page you're trying to log into, but that's how you manage cookies in requests.

Answer (score 0):

i successfully logged in with this code, you can try playing around with `requests.Session` and `urllib cookiejar` but i dont think it is possible

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
from oauth_tokens.providers.facebook import FacebookAuthRequest

req = FacebookAuthRequest(username='username', password='password')
response = req.authorized_request(url='https://facebook.com')
print response.content.count("https://facebook.com")
for x in range(5):
    print
print response.encoding
```